# Custom input[type="date"] with svg

Tags: javascript, date, firefox, input, webkit

I`m trying to custom input date with svg in Mozila. [image] Unfortunately, clickable zone is not like svg (less), how can i fix this? webkit-calendar-picker-indicator does not work in FireFox.

I tried
`input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {     bottom: 0;     cursor: pointer;     height: auto;      left: 0;     position: absolute;     right: 0;        top: 0;        width: auto;      }`,
but it does not work in FireFox

Comment: It is not very clear what you are after and what's the role of the SVG here. Should it act as a label for that input?
General advice here could probably be that if you'd make the wrapper of your input and the SVG `<label>` element (instead of current `<div class="Header...">`, you should have convenient clickable area around all children.

Comment: Is there some way you could identify the input you want to style that isn’t WebKit-specific? Its class, maybe?

Comment: @myf the role of svg is being an icon for input. Thanks for advice with lable, but it won`t help

Comment: @padeso i need to make arrow area of input bigger, so i know only WebKit-specific for this purpose